# Android Toast/Dialog show detect, and get the text

Tags: android, dialog, toast, detect

I am working on a project, aiming at a SDK, which APP developer can use it to know APP users' behavior. However, I came into a problem. I working on it for several days, but get nothing. My difficulty is how to know when a Toast/Dialog is show and get the text in them. Since I am developping a SDK, so it's better not to be add some additional code where the Toast/Dialog show for the developers' convience. This SDK just requires developers add one code in every onCreat() of each Activity. So every can help me? This drives me crazy!